# Is it possible to have more than one type for a CustomPropertyDrawer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, custom-properties

I am currently trying to make a `CustomPropertyDrawer` in Unity for the inspector. The point is that all Lists and arrays with the Attribute gets a better looking then it is normally. Now I ran into the problem that I would need a code like that `[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(List<> || Array))]` this will obviously not work like that but I need something that works similar to this.

Comment: you can make dedicated propertydrawers that all inherit from the same root and introduce no new code - this way you can have one [CustomPropertyDrawer] tag per class

Comment: you can still implement one of them and then let the other one inherit from it and use the inherited one for the other type I guess

Comment: Oh and I guess you could also simply without inheritance use two `[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Array)][CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(List<>)]` but not sure on this one ;)

Comment: I will give that a try too :D